# How to convert value / string content of cell to nsindexpath

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have a UICollectionView which is populated with content from CoreData.  When the view loads I want to preselect/highlight some of the cells.

I have been able to get the items preselected using the code below.  The highlighting isn't working as seamlessly as I would like, but I can make it work.

```
- (void)preSelect {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:5];
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    if ([[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] isSelected]) {
        [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        NSLog(@"selected count %i",[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems].count);
    }
}
```

I DO NOT want to have the preselects hardcoded however. I want to do something like:

```
NSIndexPath = indexPath where [value of cell] isEqual:@"NSString";
```

or better yet

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"myClass"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *object, NSError *error){    NSString *abc = [object valueForKey:@"myKey"];
NSIndexPath = indexPath where cell.text = abc;
```

Comment: Not the most elegant answer, but I can basically get there with a long stream of if statements checking the the value of each.  I'd love a better answer:

Answer (score 0):

If you use cellForItemAtIndexPath that way, then your code is fatally broken.

cells only exist for items on the screen, and as you scroll around and items are removed from the screen or appear on the screen, cells are reused for new items.

The UIView method cellForItemAtIndexPath returns nil if the index path is not on the screen. And if you change the background colour of a cell, then it keeps that background colour as it other items move on the screen, reusing the cell with the background colour that you just set. Good fun when you debug it.

The place where you modify the cells is in your implementation of the UIViewController method cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Thanks.  I did notice that it didn't work and that was happening!!!  Still looking for a good solution.  Can you explain a little more about what you mean by your last sentence?  This is where I was triggering the code. Is there specific code you suggest for this approach that will work?  Deleting it as a possible answer.